# Google sign in stuck after adding requestscopes method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, google-calendar-api

Is there any way to fix this? for some reason whenever I add request scopes google sign in gets stuck
loading indefinitely.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
                .RequestIdToken(client_id)
                .RequestScopes(new Scope (CalendarService.Scope.Calendar))
                .RequestEmail()
                .Build();
```

Im assuming its going to ask for permission but it doesnt load. using xamarin.android app

Comment: When working with the new calendar APIs in your application, the first thing you need to do is add the appropriate permissions to the Android manifest. The permissions you need to add are `android.permisson.READ_CALENDAR` and `android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR`, depending on whether you are reading and/or writing calendar data.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I added the permissions and right after I select the google account it starts looping.

Comment: what happen if you don't add RequestScopes?

Comment: Hello, I tried using android studios and java and I still get the same result. Whenever I remove .requestScopes, im able to log in fine. I also added the Google Calendar API to the console project and removed it too .

Comment: search some info, still find any solution, so you solve your problem now?

Answer (score 2):

There's a solution for this that worked for me:
Go to Google API Console -> OAuth Consent Screen -> Change Publishing status to 'in production'. It might give a warning but just click okay.

[image]

Comment: It worked. Had seen an answer elsewhere but didn't know what to make of it. It just said change the 'consent screen'. But here you've been very clear with the instructions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google has fixed the problem, and now the old solution appears to be the problem.

Returning back to Testing now fixed the hanging problem which started happening again in two of my apps that I had flipped to Production to fix the problem months ago.